# Check values before submit with document.form.action

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, pdf, submit

On my web application I have a form with two `<select>`.
One represents the month and another the year.

```
<form id="reportform" target="_blank">
    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="14">
    <thead>
        <th class="report" colspan="2"><spring:message code="label.month"/></th>                        
        <th class="report" colspan="2"><spring:message code="label.year" /></th>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="centerId" value="${center.centerId}" type="hidden">
        </td>
        <td class="date">
            <select class="select-input-month-report" id="select-input-month" name="month">
                <option selected="selected" value="0"><spring:message code="label.select" /></option>
                <option value="1"><spring:message code="label.january" /></option>
                <option value="2"><spring:message code="label.february" /></option>
                <option value="3"><spring:message code="label.march" /></option>
                <option value="4"><spring:message code="label.april" /></option>
                <option value="5"><spring:message code="label.may" /></option>
                <option value="6"><spring:message code="label.june" /></option>
                <option value="7"><spring:message code="label.july" /></option>
                <option value="8"><spring:message code="label.august" /></option>
                <option value="9"><spring:message code="label.september" /></option>
                <option value="10"><spring:message code="label.october" /></option>
                <option value="11"><spring:message code="label.november" /></option>
                <option value="12"><spring:message code="label.december" /></option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="date">
            <select class="select-input-year-report" id="select-input-year" name="year">
                <option value="0" selected="selected"><spring:message code="label.select" /></option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <input id="go" class="go" type="submit" value="Report">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

On server side PDF is generated (using `iTextPdf`) according to month and year selected on UI.

When month and year are correct PDF is generated properly but when user doesn't selects a correct month and year (one of them is zero) then I get an error in my back end.

I would like to check that month or year are different than 0 with javascript code and minimize changes in my `@Controller`. But I am not able to check values of month and year and call the back-end service using `document.reportform.action`.

```
@Controller
public class ReportController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/report.pdf", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getPdfReport(@ModelAttribute ReportRequest request) throws DAOException {        

        ...
        return mav;
    }
}
```

I call to service like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        var zeros = checkDate();
        if(zeros == '0'){
            document.reportform.action = "/report.pdf";
        }
    });
});

function checkDate(){
    var zeros = 0;
    if(document.getElementById("select-input-month").value == 0){
        zeros++;
    }
    if(document.getElementById("select-input-year").value == 0){
        zeros++;
    }
    return zeros;
}
```

Help will be appreciated.

**Update:**
I get Javascript error: `document.reportform.action = "/report.pdf" not defined.`

Comment: It is not a good idea with run validations with javascript only. You should be doing it in the controller too.

Comment: You're already using jQuery then why don't you use `$("#select-input-month").val()`?

Comment: You don't actually say what's wrong with it.  Can you explain what it's doing, or not doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form id="reportform" target="_blank" method="post">

    $(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(e){
            var zeros = checkDate();
            if(zeros == '0'){
                $(this).attr("action","/report.pdf");
            }
            else{
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('Select month and year');
            }
        });
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/URfkN/1/

```
@Controller
public class ReportController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/report.pdf", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getPdfReport(@ModelAttribute ReportRequest request, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) throws DAOException {        

        String month = httpRequest.getParameter("month");
        String year= httpRequest.getParameter("year");
        ....
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks close but I get an error 'GET' method not supported. I have defined as POST because I am sending data to back-end. Any idea?

Comment: <form id="reportform" target="_blank" method="post">

Comment: Right, I forgot to change the method. But now I get an issue when constructing the ReportRequest object. It is supposed parameters are send on body response and not in URL, right?

Comment: I don't see any model attribute in your html. May be you can use the HTTP request itself.

Comment: No need to do it. When I send the form the request body has 3 parameters. SpringMVC created my ReportRequest object directly (`@ModelAttribute ReportRequest request`). I am checking your solution that can work but is not so smart than using all SpringMVC power.

Comment: It is working. I accept your answer but I will try to find the way to make it work using SpringMVC `@ModelAttribute` tag. Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, you need to send the model to the html first (possibly in the GET call for this page) and only then you will get it back in your controller POST method. In this case your select should look like this: `<select class="select-input-month-report" id="select-input-month" name="month" value="${request.month}">` (assuming month is a field in your `ReportRequest` object)

Comment: In fact it is not necessary. It is possible to send JSON on request body to the server where all members match in name with particular Model object attributes. SpringMVC does the work and generates a Model object with those attributes. I did in some cases but in this case I am not able to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Using JQuery it is pretty simple:

```
    $(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($("#select-input-month").val()=='0' || $("#select-input-year").val()=='0')
        {
            document.reportform.action = "/report.pdf";
        }
        });
    });
```